# Request Body is null in Go lang (Postman)

Tags: json, http, go, postman, gorilla

I am using Postman to post the json string on localhost. The json string that  Iam passing in Postman is :

```
{
    “name”: "foo"
}
```

However, when I retrieve the data in my test function, the `req.Body` i get something like this : `&{%!s(*io.LimitedReader=&{0xc0820142a0 0}) <nil> %!s(*bufio.Reader=<nil>) %!s(bool=false) %!s(bool=true) {%!s(int32=0) %!s(uint32=0)} %!s(bool=true) %!s(bool=false) %!s(bool=false)}`

I wish to get the name:foo in the request body.

My go lang code for the same is :

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Input struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}


func test(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var t Input
    json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&t)
    fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%s\n", req.Body)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test", test)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting blank data in the req.Body attribute ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should print `t` not `req.Body`. And **please**: Handle each and every error.

Comment: @Volker : I tried that . Printing t gives me a blank '{}' . Nothing inside it :(

Comment: How did you print `t`? Like `"%s", t.name` or `"%#v", t`. an output of "{}" seems strange. And handle every error.

Comment: @Volker When I use fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%s\n", t) , I get {} . For fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%#v", t)  I get main.Input{Name:""} in the output . Any inputs on this ?

Comment: I guess your JSON decoding fails and you ignore the error - the JSON you posted above does look strange because it uses these "special" quotation marks around `name`. So, as @Volker suggested, try handling _all_ the errors first.

Comment: Yes handling the error was an issue . I just got to know how much important error-handling is in GO . 
Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reuqes Body should be empty because you already read all from it. But that not the issue.
From your question, it seem your input is not valid JSON (you have **“** which is different with **"**).
The **Decode** method will return error, you should check that.

```
if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&t); err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: THe decode method did not return any error but worked fine with the code you suggested. I still wonder sir what did the err variable had a role here. ANy insights would be appreciated. 
thanks a lot:)

Comment: Not a magic like you think. If no error return (err == nil) then the Decode success. In your case when the `t` variale empty, must be some error happened!

Comment: I got the same problem, and didn't solve it by the code upstair